# Xcode 7.3: app delegate can't access its own objects, context is claiming to capture an objective-C object but self isn't available

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

In xcode 7.3 on MacOS 10.11.3 and 10.11.4, when I stop the debugger inside any app delegate method and try to examine any object instantiated inside the app delegate, or even the app delegate itself, I get this warning in the debugger:

```
 error: warning: Stopped in a context claiming to capture an Objective-C object pointer, but 'self' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context

 error: member reference type 'AppDelegate *const' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

 error: incomplete definition of type 'AppDelegate'

 note: forward declaration of 'AppDelegate'

 error: 2 errors parsing expression
```

This particular time I was in the app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method`, but stopping in any method in the app delegate, at any point in running the app, gives the same error when trying to look at any of the app delegate's objects.

This does not happen with xcode 7.2. I do notice that in 7.2 that `self` for the app delegate is listed as (AppDelegate *), while in 7.3 it is (AppDelegate *const). Clicking on the disclosure arrow next to self for the app delegate does not reveal anything in 7.3, while it does in 7.2.

This is both in the simulator and on an actual device.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

August

Comment: I meet this problem too. someone says it's Xcode bug.I reinstall Xcode on another computer.but still not working.

Comment: But in my case, if you renew a project. Everything is fine.Maybe something wrong with Xcode project. But I checked the build setting,every thing seems fine. which make me confused!I have spent nearly 5 hours to fix this! But failed! I have to revert my Xcode version to 7.2..

Comment: I have the same problem with a swift VC that i instantiate from storyboar then try to access a IBOutlet from outside, before viewdidload is called. In objc the same thing works.

Answer (score 6):

I meet problems too with Object C (not tested on swift 2). I try down command line tool to 7.2.1 but not working, after 1 hour I try access property by "[]" instead "." . It worked =)).

Example:

```
 [Restaurant name]
```

instead of

```
Restaurant.name
```

Updated : found another ways to fix this bug for object C project

[Xcode 7.3 debugger not showing custom class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151708/xcode-7-3-debugger-not-showing-custom-class-variables)

Hope it helpfull

Comment: I found the problem. I had included the header for the app delegate in the pct file, to make the delegate globally available. In previous versions of XCode this worked, in 7.3 it does not. I've removed the header from the pch file and the delegate object is viewable again.

Answer (score 6):

In Build Settings, try setting `Precompile Prefix Header` to `NO`.