# How to debug member variable (ie., Array, Dictionary) in LLDB?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I've declared a Global Array/ Dictionary in Interface like below.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{

    NSDictionary *dictionary;

    NSArray *array;

}
```

I'm doing API calls and storing values in these array & dictionaries. I'd like to print the contents of the array/dictionary in LLDB during Runtime.

When i try to print these global variable, it gives me the following error.

```
(lldb) po assigneeArr
error: warning: Stopped in a context claiming to capture an Objective-C object pointer, but 'self' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context
error: use of undeclared identifier 'assigneeArr'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

So how can i debug this globally declared variable??

[image]

Comment: You should be able to access it while in scope, so you can put a breakpoint anywhere in the same class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved my issue by changing **Enable Clang Module Debugging** in **Apple LLVM 7.1 Language Modules** as following screen shot

[image: Enable Clang Module Debugging]

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176158/4014369

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't global variables; they are instance variables, so you need an instance of `ViewController` before you can see their value.

Once you have the instance then it's as simple as using the `->` operator (`vc` is the instance):

```
po vc->dictionary
```

Note: I would recommend using an underscore to prefix the names of instance variables in order to avoid confusion with parameters and local variables.

Comment: How to create instance of Viewcontroller in LLDB Window ?

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan you don't; your app has the instance (somewhere).

Comment: Trojanfoe is right. By the way, such variable is called member variables. Global variable is seldom used in Objective-C, and not recommended in other languages. Singleton pattern is more often used.

Comment: I tried using `po self->assigneeArr` But again it gives me following error `po self->assigneeArr 
error: warning: Stopped in a context claiming to capture an Objective-C object pointer, but 'self' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context
error: member access into incomplete type 'TSEventApprovalDescViewController'
note: forward declaration of 'TSEventApprovalDescViewController'
error: 1 errors parsing expression`

Comment: Sounds like you aren't in a method of `ViewController`, which is the only place that `self` would point to the instance.  Sounds like you are having difficulty getting this `ViewController` instance, but I'm afraid I cannot offer help on this as it's not been revealed in your code.

Comment: I'd a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and I'm trying to print values retrieved from DB. I'll share the screen.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan That sounds like it should work.

Comment: Did u see the screen ?  How can i access that member variable  **"assigneeArr"**??

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan Well in this context, I would have expected `self->assigneeArr` to work (assuming `assigneeArr` is an instance variable, declared the way `dictionary` and `array` are in the code you posted).

Answer (score 1):

Please do below steps:

1. Press keyboard **Command+Shift+y.** It will open debug area for your project.

2. At right bottom of debug area you can find the icon of **Trash**. Near Trash icon you can find two options like **Hide the variables view** and **Hide the Console**. Both make on (It will display with blue border)

3. Put the break point on your `ViewController` where you are using your **dictionary / array**. 

4. You can find your **dictionary / array** value in Left side of your debug area.

5. Please do right click on your **dictionary / array**. you will be get first option **i.e.Print description of dictionary / array**.

6. After clicking on it you will get its whole value in **console**. (Right side of debug area)


Also you can refer below screen shot for the same.

[image]